# Observing all outgoing/incoming network connections, sorted by process .exe

Tags: windows, windows-7, networking, network-monitor

What Windows 7 tool (possibly *portable freeware*, with a GUI) allows to **show a list of network outgoing/incoming connections, sorted by process?** Something similar to the usual Task manager (`taskmgr.exe`) but for networking:

Example:

```
chrome.exe                                 [X] Click to block
      + 198.237.216.12:80    
      + 198.237.216.11:1827                 (collapsable list that we can open/close)
      ...
avastservice.exe                           [X] Click to block
      + 118.237.216.47:9173
blahblah.exe                               [X] Click to block
      + 122.222.116.11:13
      => this one looks suspicious, we never asked this software to 
         have connections, let's block it!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution: [CurrPorts](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) is perfect for this!

[image]